# Jumbo frame on Nexus 5k

Tags: cisco, qos, mtu, cisco-nexus-5k

I would like to enable the jumbo frame support on my N5k for specific SCSI trafic.

I've read we can't do it per interface but only on the system itself :

```
policy-map type network-qos JUMBO_MTU
  class type network-qos class-default
    mtu 9216

!

system qos
  service-policy type network-qos JUMBO_MTU
```

But this enables jumbo frame on the whole switch. Can I identify the SCSI traffic on the policy-map so that it's applied just for the traffic I want?

And so the jumbo from other type of traffic would be processed normally ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, you just have to classify the traffic.  Here is an example where we classify iSCSI into its own class.  The class-default class will match any other traffic.

```
class-map type qos match-all iSCSI
  match protocol iscsi
  match cos 4

policy-map type qos POLICY-QOS
  class iSCSI
    set qos-group 3
  class class-fcoe
    set qos-group 1

class-map type network-qos iSCSI
  match qos-group 3

policy-map type network-qos JUMBO
  class type network-qos iSCSI
    mtu 9216
    pause no-drop
  class type network-qos class-fcoe
    pause no-drop
    mtu 2158
  class type network-qos class-default
    multicast-optimize


system qos
  service-policy type network-qos JUMBO
  service-policy type qos input POLICY-QOS
```

Just an additional note, you should modify the classification to match your environment and requirements.  You can classify based on other criteria as well such as IP address.

```
class-map type qos match-all iSCSI
  match access-group name PERMIT-ANY
```

**Edit:**

[N5K Configuration Guide](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus5000/sw/qos/b_Cisco_Nexus_5000_Series_NX-OS_Quality_of_Service_Configuration_Guide/Cisco_Nexus_5000_Series_NX-OS_Quality_of_Service_Configuration_Guide_chapter3.html#con_1056888)

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't understand all the commands but I will work on it. If you tell me that I can change MTU for iSCSI and doing noting for other traffic it's perfect

Comment: Just an obvious question, as I read it, this system qos is applied on all FEX connected to the N5k ? Sorry but another question, does it hurt the cpu to add that on the system qos?

Comment: It applies to all interfaces including FEX.  I believe the QoS is done in hardware and shouldn't impact the CPU.  I haven't seen any CPU increase on our N5Ks.  I added a link to the N5K config guide that might be helpful.